# Exemption from wearing tallit katan other than in extreme heat?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, tzitzis, tallit-katan

בס"ד
I saw an exemption for wearing a tallit katan if the tempature is extremely high. I think this was cited by the Tzitz Eliezer, but I can't find it.

Are there other exceptions?

Answer (score 3):

Rav Yitzchak Abadi  (Ohr Yitzchak vol 1:8) writes that if it is uncformatable wearing tzizts (obviously coming from a true discomfort) then one would be exempt. Such examples he gives is working out,or it is hot outside. It should be pointed out that mitzvos of tzizts is a very beloved mitzvah and should be taken seriously.

Text:

[image]

Comment: See also https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3429/170